# Hide CheckBoxes When Form is Minimized

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, visibility, show-hide, formclosing

I have three CheckBoxes that I need to hide whenever my form is closed or minimized.  I know how do hide them with the FormClosing Event. Here is what I have for that:

```
Public Sub Tickers_Closed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Nordeen_Investing_3.CheckBox_NASDAQ.Hide()
    Nordeen_Investing_3.CheckBox_NYSE.Hide()
    Nordeen_Investing_3.CheckBox_AMEX.Hide()
End Sub
```

How do I hide them when the form is minimized?

Comment: Look at the [`Form_ResizeEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend(v=vs.110).aspx) event - you can then check `Me.WindowState = Minimized`. That said, _why_ would you ever want to do this? If it's minimised or closed, it can't handle input anyway (at least not via stock form event handlers)

Comment: The `CheckBoxes` are on a `MenuStrip` that is contained on my `Parent Form`.  But I only want to see them when the `Child Form` is maximized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a combination of both answers.  Here is what worked:

```
Private Sub Tickers_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
    If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
        Nordeen_Investing_3.CheckBox_NASDAQ.Hide()
        Nordeen_Investing_3.CheckBox_NYSE.Hide()
        Nordeen_Investing_3.CheckBox_AMEX.Hide()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for taking the time to come back and post a solution that worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a resize event in vb.net.  Inside this event, you just put an if statement that would look something like ..

```
Private Sub Tickers_Resize(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Resize

     if me.minimizebox  then
         Nordeen_Investing_3.CheckBox_NASDAQ.Hide()
         Nordeen_Investing_3.CheckBox_NYSE.Hide()
         Nordeen_Investing_3.CheckBox_AMEX.Hide()
     end if
end sub
```

Comment: That looks good but I get this error `Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'System.Drawing.Size'.`

Comment: maybe try Nordeen_Investing_3.CheckBox_NASDAQ.visible = false  instead of using the hide function.